# how to create pop-over screen in angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I want to create page which contain some data. that page can be open on click on something. i opening this page from parent.

```
`<div class="dashboard-lead-detail-view col-md-4">
 <lead-detail-view *ngIf="leadDetail"
                    [leadDetail]="leadDetail">
 </lead-detail-view>
 </div>`
```

so my question is that what should i use ? .whether i use modal or something .

below image shows :

[image]

or i will use simple horizontal form. above image will open by there is button on left hand side.when i click on that it will open , i am confuse.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose best option for this feature is bsModalService with Components

check sample and demo, here:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component

Comment: thanx , but i got solution